# BigQuery Standard SQL - Cumulative Count of (almost) Duplicated Rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

With the following data:

| id | field | eventTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 1 | A | 2 |
| 1 | B | 3 |
| 1 | A | 4 |
| 1 | B | 5 |
| 1 | B | 6 |
| 1 | B | 7 |

For visualisation purposes, I would like to turn it into the below. Consecutive occurrences of the same `field` value essentially get aggregated into one.

| id | field | eventTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ax2 | 1 |
| 1 | B | 3 |
| 1 | A | 4 |
| 1 | Bx3 | 5 |

I will then use `STRING_AGG()` to turn it into `"Ax2 > B > A > Bx3"`.

I've tried using `ROW_NUMBER()` to count the repeated instances, with the plan being to utilise the highest row number to modify the string in `field`, but if I partition on `eventTime`, there are no consecutive "duplicates", and if I don't partition on it then all rows with the same `field` value are counted - not just consecutive ones.

I though about bringing in the previous `field` with `LAG()` for a comparison to reset the row count, but that only works for transitions from one `field` value to the other and is a problem if the same `field` is repeated consecutively.

I'm been struggling with this to the point where I'm considering writing a script that just `CASE WHEN`s up to a reasonable number of consecutive hits, but I've seen it get as high as 17 on a given day and really don't want to be doing that!

My other alternative will just be to enforce a maximum number of `field` values to help control this, but now I've started this problem I'd quite like to solve it without that, if at all possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just use `lag()` to detect when the value of `field` changes.  You can now do that with `qualify`:

```
select t.*
from t
where 1=1
qualify lag(field, 1, '') over (partition by id order by eventtime) <> field;
```

For your final step, you can use a subquery:

```
select id, string_agg(field, '->' order by eventtime)
from (select t.*
      from t
      where 1=1
      qualify lag(field, 1, '') over (partition by id order by eventtime) <> field
     ) t
group by id;
```

Comment: I need to not lose count of how many times the value appears consecutively. I've tried implementing this quickly but it seems this just condenses the values down to one occurrence without maintaining a count, though I have just learned about qualify so maybe I'm not quite using it right.

I've got a working solution using LAG to provide a unique ID on a field change, and then `COALESCE(LAG...` to fill in these IDs. Then I can GROUP BY this new ID to get a count. I'm going to try and clean it up before editing it in as a solution.

Comment: @LiamGalbraith . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  Ask a *new* question, if this is not exactly the question that you intended to ask.

Comment: I disagree, the desired results in both the table and the string show a modified field value to reflect the count, and the title states a "count". Granted, on reading back the "*essentially* get aggregated into one" and title could be clearer by dropping the "cumulative", but I still believe the desired outcome should have helped. Also with this exact answer, BigQuery throws the error "Argument 3 to analytic function 'lag' has to be a constant. Found Deref.". Either way, thanks for your help and introducing me to something new.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below

```
select id, 
  any_value(field) || if(count(1) = 1, '', 'x' || count(1)) field, 
  min(eventTime) eventTime 
from (
  select id, field, eventTime, 
    countif(ifnull(flag, true)) over(partition by id order by eventTime) grp 
  from (
    select id, field, eventTime,
      field != lag(field) over(partition by id order by eventTime) flag
    from `project.dataset.table`
  )
)
group by id, grp
# order by eventTime
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]